# Need hard disk recommendation for linux home server

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid

I'm planing to build a little linux homeserver. It will mainly be used for storage and maybe as an media pc.

I plan to build a software raid5 with 4 1.5TB or 2TB hard drives.
I already decided to use the Western Digital Caviar Green 1.5 TB drive,
but then I read about some problems with the WD green series about many drives failing and that they are not recommended for raid anyway.

Of course, I couldn't find much facts on the issues so I thought I just ask here ;-)

What hard drives would you recommended for a software raid5 setup?

As I only need it for storage, the whole thing doesn't have to be too fast.
So I prefer a cheap price and silence to great performance.

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you the Western Digital Caviar Black (1 or 2 TB) drives.

Model n.: WD2001FASS - 2TB

Model n.: WD1002FAES - 1TB

If your motherboard is SATA3 compatible, you can use WD1002FAEX.

Comment: For a motherboard, I am going to use a Zotac H55-ITX.  
Also I knew about the WD black series, but they are a little to expensive for my budget....  
What do you think about the Hitachi DeskStar 7K2000 2000GB, SATA II (HDS722020ALA330) or the Samsung Ecco series?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should get two different drives from two different makers, since RAID is supposed to protect from the failure of a drive and when one dies the other is a crutch until you replace it and by then there will be a whole new set of drives with potential problems from which to choose. Two different drives will mitigate the whole "What if they fail" while two of the same manufacturing batch increases the odds they fail at the same time.

No matter what you get you'll find people recommending you don't use them.

And the best answer is that if the data is important, you'll want to have a backup scheme in place that doesn't rely on RAID.

Comment: Seconded. The only thing to kind of keep an eye on is to get them all of the same 'speed' so you don't hobble the fast ones with the slow ones.  I've got a WD, a Seagate, and a Hitachi in my server (RAID0 with a hot spare).

Comment: @pjz-true, I should have mentioned matching speeds on the drives.